# Get WSDL object into a SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, wsdl

So I hate to ask this but the last 10 hours of searching and attempting to code have turned up nothing.

I have a visual studio project with an SQL database attached. I need to pull data from a google weather service API into the sql table.

The webservice call is to this site [google api call](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=82070)

As well as a couple other sites like accuweather and NOAA to show the differences between the three. The projects goal is to see whether the data is relatively the same or if different weather stations are bring used, and if so does it cause a significant difference in the way the weather is reported to the user.

What I'm missing is an interpreter for the object can allow me to put the temp, humidity ect into a sql table

Has anyone done this before and have some tips or references?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Currently I have pulled the object from the webservice, but I can't parse (probably not the correct word) the object.

Comment: your question is very unclear. Try providing more information to point out which google weather service you are using.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704437/c-sharp-pull-xml-data-from-googles-weather-api/7704561#7704561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can parse the response using Linq to XML

> Live Example: http://balexandre.com/stackoverflow/7789623/

The link also include the source code, but the parsing using Linq to XML is quick easy, fun and extremely simple:

```
private GoogleWheatherInfo parseGoogleWeatherResponse(string url)
{
    GoogleWheatherInfo gw = new GoogleWheatherInfo();

    // get the XML
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);

    // parse data
    gw.ForecastInformation = (from x in doc.Descendants("forecast_information")
                              select new GWForecastInfo
                              {
                                  City = x.Descendants("city").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                                  PostalCode = x.Descendants("postal_code").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                                  Latitude = long.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Descendants("latitude_e6").First().Attribute("data").Value) ? "0" : x.Descendants("latitude_e6").First().Attribute("data").Value),
                                  Longitude = long.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Descendants("longitude_e6").First().Attribute("data").Value) ? "0" : x.Descendants("longitude_e6").First().Attribute("data").Value),
                                  ForecastDate = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Descendants("forecast_date").First().Attribute("data").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                  CurrentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Descendants("current_date_time").First().Attribute("data").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                  UnitSystem = x.Descendants("unit_system").First().Attribute("data").Value
                              }).Single();

    gw.CurrentCondition = (from x in doc.Descendants("current_conditions")
                           select new GWCurrentCondition
                           {
                               Condition = x.Descendants("condition").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                               TemperatureC = long.Parse(x.Descendants("temp_c").First().Attribute("data").Value),
                               TemperatureF = long.Parse(x.Descendants("temp_f").First().Attribute("data").Value),
                               Humidity = x.Descendants("humidity").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                               Image = x.Descendants("icon").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                               Wind = x.Descendants("wind_condition").First().Attribute("data").Value
                           }).Single();

    gw.ForecastConditions = (from x in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions")
                             select new GWForecastCondition
                             {
                                 DayOfWeek = x.Descendants("day_of_week").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                                 Low = double.Parse(x.Descendants("low").First().Attribute("data").Value),
                                 High = double.Parse(x.Descendants("high").First().Attribute("data").Value),
                                 Image = x.Descendants("icon").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                                 Condition = x.Descendants("condition").First().Attribute("data").Value,
                             }).ToList();

    return gw;
}
```

I hope this gives you some knowledge on how easy is to parse any XML document.