# c# getting informaion from xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

A want get all information which are in located in `<forecast_conditions></forecast_conditions>` tag for first ta I use

```
var for_cod = from currentCond in xdoc.Root.Descendants("current_conditions")
                         select currentCond;
```

I don;t know how to get information from 2,3 `<forecast_conditions></forecast_conditions>` tags because it have same names, maybe you have any ideas?

xml file: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hleng=eng

Comment: post your xml file, or part of xml file which contains forecast_conditions

Comment: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hleng=eng

Comment: You are aware that you said once `currentCond` and once `currentCoud`? Is it a type here in this post or also in your code?

Comment: Sry i made mistake when rewrite code

Comment: Why are you querying for `current_conditions` if you want `forecast_conditions`? Please clarify if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Do you want all the forecast_condition in one query ? then simple query against forecast_condition, you will get a result set containing all forecast_conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly need. If you want to get all forecast_conditions for in a result set you can use this simple query

```
 var query  = from t in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions")
                         select t;
```

You may wanna see [Weather Information from Google Weather using ASP.NET and LINQ to XML](http://www.devtechie.com/post/2012/01/16/Weather-Information-from-Google-Weather-using-ASPNET-and-LINQ-to-XML.aspx), also check out this article [Using Google Weather API In A C# Application](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/153911-c#using-google-weather-api-in-a-c#-application/). Its not using LINQ though. Also check out this thread [C# Pull XML data from google's weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704437/c-sharp-pull-xml-data-from-googles-weather-api)